# How to get current page using start index, items per page, total items, and total pages? (PHP)

Tags: php, pagination

For example, let's say:

```
$startIndex = 21; 
$totalItems = 100;
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $itemsPerPage);  // (10)

$currentpage = //I am stumped here.
```

What would $currentpage be, based on $startIndex?

I'm working on pagination and it's kicking my butt. I know it's probably some very simple math, but I can't think right now.

Comment: How do you pass the current page index? If by get, you'll use something like $currentpage = $_GET['currentpage'];

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With 10 items per page and assuming your item count/numbering starts at 1, page 1 contains items 1 to 10, page 2 contains items 11 to 20, page 3 contains 21 to 30, and so on.

So,

```
$currentPage = ceil(($startIndex - 1) / $itemsPerPage) + 1;
```

I used [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to make sure you have an integer number, which is rounded up so the current page number is correct.

---

If your item count starts at 0, so page 1 contains items 0 to 9, you can skip the `- 1` and `+ 1` parts of the formula:

```
$currentPage = ceil(($startIndex) / $itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct. Consider a set of 14 records, with a limit of 7 per page. If your startIndex = 7, the page should be 2, but ceil(7/7) = 1. With 100 records, a limit of 10 and a startIndex of 50 the page should be 6, but 50/10 = 5. The answer of Sammitch is correct, ((startIndex-1)/itemsPerPage) + 1, which for these two examples gives ceil(((7-1)/14)+1) = 2, and ceil((50-1/10)+1) = 6. The other consideration is startIndex of 0 which you have to handle separately.

Comment: You are right, the answer is a little 'ambiguous', the formula is/was correct when item count starts at zero, but my explanation used item 1 as first one. The answer of Sammitch is lacking the `ceil()` part (and any explanation at all), so I updated my answer to have the correct/full formula and explanation.

Answer (score 10):

You slept a lot in math class, didn't you?

```
$currentpage = (($startIndex - 1) / $itemsPerPage) + 1;
```

Comment: +1 for sleep... could use some of that right now. Need a floor/ceil in there, though, to round off the page number. don't know of too many books (or websites) that have "page 2.35612"

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
$startIndex = 21; 
$totalItems = 100;
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$totalPages = ($totalItems / $itemsPerPage);  // (10)
```

then

```
$currentpage = $startIndex/$itemsPerPage; //Make sure that it uses integer division
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to use `floor` to get current page

```
pagesTotal = int(ceil(count / limit))
pagesCurrent = int(floor(offset / limit) + 1)
```